# Questions about nominal data

Tags: categorical-data

Can nominal data have uncountably many values?

Are categorical data the same as nominal data?

Are discrete data the same as nominal data?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no r in *nominal*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see:

1) I think it depends on how you mean "uncountably". In a strict sense, no. You could count every atom in the universe, at least in theory. But in a more practical sense - sure. A list of all possible molecules is finite but it's so big that the finiteness is not practical.

2) Categorical data can certainly be nominal; they can also be ordinal (e.g. opinions given on a Likert scale). You can even categorize (and people frequently do) data that is interval or ratio, and sometimes you can uncategorize it.

3) As @Gung pointed out, a count variable is discrete but not categorical. They are also not nominal - indeed, counts don't fit perfectly into Stevens' classification - they are discrete but ratio, in that e.g. a person with 3 cars has 3 times more than a person who has 1.

Comment: This is good info, but note that a *count* (eg, the number of complications per month in a surgical center) is discrete, but is not categorical data.

Comment: Oh, good example, +1.  I will modify my answer. Counts are tricky

Comment: What's the difficulty with counts? Ratios of counts make sense as zero is a natural origin for counts and so they are ratio scale. Discrete vs continuous is a distinction independent of nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio. (Whether there are interval scale measurements that are discrete is an interesting question.) Categories can of course be counted in many cases, just as the amount of a category can be measured.

Comment: The opening sections of Agresti, Alan. 2013. _Categorical data analysis._ Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley are good on these minor terminological issues. They are visible via http://www.amazon.com/Categorical-Analysis-Series-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470463635/

Comment: @gung Agreed, but paradoxically or not most of the analysis of categorical data is focused on counts of categories (even if the counts are 0,1).

Comment: The difficulty with counts is that dividing them doesn't make sense. With most ratio variables, it does: Half of 15 pounds is 7.5 pounds; but in some sense, half of 3 cars doesn't make sense: You can't have 1.5 cars.

Comment: @Nick, Peter: Are count data ordinal, interval or ratio?

For example count data that have Poisson distribution are discussed in categorical data analysis by agresti. Categorical data, asaik, only consist of nominal data and ordinal data.

Comment: @Tim There is no great answer to this question; count data don't fit well on Stevens' scheme.

Comment: @Peter Flom I see that you are troubled by this, but I am not. You can have half of six bottles. Half of 3 cars happens to be the average of cars/household when the sample is our household and our neighbours': no absurdity, just a consequence of the mathematics. It doesn't have to correspond to anything physical. You could divide our car in two, but I would rather you didn't. You can have an average family size that is not an integer.  Generations of teachers and students have learned that the latter is just a consequence of reasonable principles.

Comment: I think your latest questions in the comments have already been answered. @Peter Flom and I disagree a bit about how (and how far) counts fit into the Stevens scheme; I suspect that we might agree that this is, at most, a problem for the Stevens scheme, which is not a comprehensive framework for modern statistics, and not something with deep consequences elsewhere. As I commented earlier, much of categorical data analysis is about handling counts of categories; why should that surprise or trouble you or anyone else?